# Implement a Thread on a Button that adds items to a RecyclerView

Tags: android, multithreading, optimization, android-recyclerview, android-button

In my app, I have 2 activities. The first activity is the main screen, and the second activity is the shop screen. The 2nd activity contains 2 fragments. I have 2 RecyclerViews located in the first fragment:

- Shopping cart (initially empty)  --> **spritesSelected**
- Food List (constant size)  --> **spritesList**

Whenever the user clicks on a button to add food, the Food List RV pops up in a Dialog.

Then, whenever the user clicks on a specific food item in the RV, another Dialog shows up:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfNYx.png)

Once the user enters the amount of food and confirms, the Shopping Cart RV is updated and the food is entered.

My problem is that the whole process is pretty long. Here is the **food item** code inside the Food List RV **adapter**.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (spriteSelectedRVAInterface1 != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();

                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            Sprite s = spritesSelected.get(position);
                            s.setVisibility(!s.visibility);
                            spriteSelectedRVAInterface1.onItemClicked(position);


                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

The interface is implemented in the fragment. Thus, it overrides the method `onItemClicked();` :

```
@Override
public void onItemViewClicked(Sprite sprite, Context context) {
    spriteAddDialog = new Dialog(context);
    spriteAddDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sprite_add_menu);
    spriteAddDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

    ImageButton close = spriteAddDialog.findViewById(R.id.ib_close);
    EditText enter_amount = spriteAddDialog.findViewById(R.id.edt_enter_amount);
    Button add = spriteAddDialog.findViewById(R.id.b_add);

    enter_amount.setText(String.valueOf(sprite.defaultAmount));

    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            spriteAddDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int amountEntered = Integer.parseInt(enter_amount.getText().toString());
            int amountPresent = 0;
            
            try {
                amountPresent =  spritesSelectedAmount.get(spritesSelected.indexOf(sprite));
            } catch (Exception IndexOutOfBoundsException){
                //do nothing
            }
            
            if (amountEntered + amountPresent  > sprite.maxAmountSelected){

                Toast.makeText(context, "Exceeded maximum limit of " + sprite.maxAmountSelected + " items.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                spriteAddDialog.dismiss();
                spriteListDialog.dismiss();
                onAddButtonClick(sprite, amountEntered);
            }

        }
    });

    spriteAddDialog.show();
}
```

Finally, the `onAddButtonClick()` (near the end of the above code) method:

```
public int onAddButtonClick(Sprite s, int amount) {

    if (spritesSelected.size() != 0) {
        for (Sprite sprite : spritesSelected) {
            if (s == sprite) {
                int i = spritesSelected.indexOf(sprite);
                spritesSelectedAmount.set(i, spritesSelectedAmount.get(i) + amount);
                rva2.notifyItemChanged(i);
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    spritesSelected.add(s);
    spritesSelectedAmount.add(amount);



    rva2.notifyItemInserted(spritesSelected.size()-1);

    return 1;

}
```

As you can see, a lot of work is being done on the main thread. However, I don't know what the best way to implement worker threads to handle this code. I tried allocating a thread for the entire process, but it didn't seem to speed up the program.

Comment: Do you notice any lags in your UI? The only part that would put a load to the main thread as far as I see is the for loop in the `onAddButtonClick`. Then you can execute it in an executor service then notify the `rva2` adapter back in main thread using either `runOnUiThread` or a main thread handler.

Comment: The lag in the UI happens when the 1st dialog (food list) pops up as well as adding the first element to the shopping cart (~skips like 120 frames). 

I tried implementing an executor service and used Handler, but it did not fix the problem. For some reason, only the first element causes extreme lag, but every element after that doesn't lag. I originally thought it was something to do with the RV, but the RV is created in onCreateView...

Comment: Here is my logcat:

`Skipped 133 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`
`Davey! duration=2271ms; Flags=0,....`
Then whenever I add a new food item in my cart:

`endAllActiveAnimators on 0xe6b6f950 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xbd7092f0` No lags seem to happen from now on.

Comment: The `Dialog` class you use what kind of dialog class is it? How is it implemented? May be there is too much code in it that causes the system to give this warning. Maybe you better add all relevant code like the `Dialog`'s implementation and logcat messages in your question.

Comment: Nvm, I fixed it; apparently, when I shrunk all the food item images, it worked like a charm.